# How to pass array param to url VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I want my url to look like this:`/myurl?dataRange[from]=30/10/2019&dateRange[to]=5/11/2019`

I have tried:

```
this.$router.resolve({
                    path: '/myurl/',
                    query: {                        
                        dateRange: [{ from: 'sdfsd', to: 'sdfsdf'}],
                    },
                });
```

But I get: `dateRange=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

**EDIT:**

Solved problem by use next code:

```
query: {
  'dateRange[from]': '31-10-2019',
  'dateRange[to]': '01-11-2019'
}
```

Maybe someone knows a better solution?

Comment: try with dateRange: { from: 'sdfsd', to: 'sdfsdf'},

Comment: try this query: { dateRange: [from, to] },

url will look /myurl?dateRange[]=30/10/2019&dateRange[]=5/11/2019,

and access with dateRange[0], dateRange[1]

Comment: How does your `url` look like now?

Comment: My url looks like: `%2Fmyurl%3FdataRange%5Bfrom%5D%3D30%2F10%2F2019%26dateRange%5Bto%5D%3D5%2F11%2F2019`.
But it work